# A column-safe `INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM ...`?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there some way to do a `INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM...` such that it fails if the column names do not coincide?

I'm using Postgresql 9.x The columns names are not known in advance.

Motivation: I'm doing a periodic refresh of materialized views by the (quite standard) PL/pgSQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION matview_refresh(name) RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    matview ALIAS FOR $1;
    entry matviews%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO entry FROM matviews WHERE mv_name = matview;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Materialized view % does not exist.', matview;
    END IF;

    EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || matview;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || matview  || ' SELECT * FROM ' || entry.v_name;

    UPDATE matviews SET last_refresh=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE mv_name=matview;
    RETURN;
END
```

I preferred a `TRUNCATE` followed by a `SELECT * INTO` instead of a DROP/CREATE because it seemed more light and concurrent-friendly. It would fail if someone adds/remove columns from the view (then I would do the DROP/CREATE) but, it doesn't matter, in that case the refresh would not complete and we would catch the problem soon. What does matter is what happened today: someone changed the order of two columns of the view (of the same type), and the refresh inserted bogus data.

Comment: Are you not able to specify a column list with postgresql? (`INSERT INTO t1 (col1, col2, ...) SELECT *`)

Comment: I guess he wants it to work for any tables as long as both have the same columns.

Comment: @njk: The columns names are not know in advance

Comment: What about column types, are those important?  If they don't match, the statement might not _fail_, but you could end up with poor results...  I think I'd probably look into querying the information schema tables to verify, at minimum, and get the necessary column names; it shouldn't add too much overhead, as you're _already_ using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Instead of using `SELECT *`, add a varchar column to `matviews` consisting of the column names. You can't hardwire the names into the query, but they are certainly known, or can be derived, from `v_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build this into your plpgsql function to verify that view and table share the same column names in the same sequence exactly:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM   pg_attribute
       WHERE  attrelid = matview::regclass
       AND    attisdropped = FALSE
       AND    attnum > 0
       ) t
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
       SELECT *
       FROM   pg_attribute
       WHERE  attrelid = entry.v_name::regclass
       AND    attisdropped = FALSE
       AND    attnum > 0
       ) v USING (attnum, attname) -- atttypid to check for type, too
    WHERE t.attname IS NULL
    OR    v.attname IS NULL
   ) THEN 
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Mismatch between table and view!';
END IF;
```

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` adds a row with `NULL` values for any mismatch between the list of column names. So, if `EXISTS` finds a row, something is off.

And the cast to `::regclass` would raise an exception right away if either table or view do not exist (or is out of scope - not in the `search_path` and not schema-qualified).

If you also want to check data types of the columns, just add `atttypid` to the `USING` clause.

As an aside: Querying `pg_catalog` tables is regularly faster by an order of magnitude than querying the bloated views int `information_schema` - information_schema is only good for SQL standard compliance and portability of code. Since you are writing 100 % Postgres-specific code, neither is relevant here.

Comment: Perfect. I added the `atttypid` for type checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can query information_schema.columns to get columns in the right order:

```
SELECT INTO cols array_to_string(array_agg(column_name::text), ',') 
FROM (
    SELECT column_name 
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_name = 'matview' 
    ORDER BY ordinal_position
) AS x;
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || matview  || ' SELECT ' || cols || ' FROM ' || entry.v_name;
```

You can get column list directly from pg_attribute -- just replace inner `SELECT` from `information_schema.columns` by:

```
SELECT attname AS column_name
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE attrelid = 'matview'::regclass AND attisdropped = false
ORDER BY attnum;
```